# Is it safe to move the beginning of an Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am currently dual booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04. My hard drive is split into two partitions: one containing windows (~350 GB) and one containing Ubuntu (~150 GB), in that order. I would like to shrink my windows partition and expand my Ubuntu partition. However, this would require shrinking the end of my windows partition and then expanding the beginning of my Ubuntu partition. I'm a fairly new user to Ubuntu/Linux (long time Windows user) and I recall reading before that moving the beginning of a windows partition is dangerous and shouldn't be done. Does this hold true for Linux/Ubuntu or should I be fine?

Comment: its better to use live boot of ubuntu to resize and also rebuild grub, just to be safe (but I cannot guarantee that you will not have any problems after resize)

Comment: you must backup your data before you do that!

Comment: take a look at this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/561905/significant-increase-in-booting-time-after-update-in-ubuntu-14-04), his boot time increased after upgrade, probably because all files moved away from start of partition. (just saying, not sure if thats the reason for increased boot time)

Comment: Thanks for the warnings. I will most certainly backup my data before I touch any partitions. Perhaps I'm wrong, but my understanding after reading Rod Smith's reply below was that moving the beginning of the partition copied system files to the new beginning, so the risk is if a system file is corrupted during this process. Doesn't this mean that a slow boot due to scattered system files is not a concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Everything* in a partition is identified relative to the start point of the partition. Thus, moving the start of a partition will most likely involve modifying more data in the partition than moving the end point of a partition. The more data you modify, the greater the risk of an error creeping in because of a bug, an I/O error, a power failure, etc. Note that the data being moved is filesystem data structures, which are unusually sensitive -- if a bit gets flipped in, say, an MP3 file that you're copying, you might hear a glitch in playback for one file; but if a bit gets flipped in a critical filesystem data structure, you could lose access to a whole file, a whole directory tree, or even the entire filesystem. Thus, if at all possible, you should avoid moving the start point of a partition.

That said, partition moves involving the start point of a partition usually succeed just fine; I just wouldn't go so far as to describe them as being *safe.*

Note that the extra concern with Windows partitions is a result of BIOS-mode boot loader code. As MoonSweep says, GRUB doesn't work the same way and so Linux partitions aren't as susceptible to these problems. Furthermore, EFI-mode boot loaders for Windows also don't rely as much on absolute partition locations, so you're more likely to get away with such moves of NTFS if the computer boots using EFI than if it boots using BIOS.

Comment: since all files will be away from start of partition it will take more time to seek them right? which means increase in boot time

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine. AFAIK, unlike Windows bootloader, Grub (you did install it in the MBR, right ?) doesn't rely on some record of the starting position of a partition to find it, but it uses its ordering on the disk (example: "third partition on the first disk"). That's how it finds its menu files, splash screen, etc (look at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`), so as long as you don't change the partitions order it should work. Nevertheless, always backup your important files before touching the partitions !

Comment: does doing that will not increase the boot time?

Comment: Why would that increase the boot time ?

Comment: No.  The partition table is very small and at the start of the disk, so even if internal disk caching doesn't eliminate the impact entirely, it'd still be only a single disk request to the same MBR area of the disk.  We're talking less than a millisecond.

Comment: since all files will be away from start of partition it will take more time to seek them right? which means increase in boot time

Comment: Technically, yes, but will this even be noticeable ? Compared to before, that would only result in one bigger initial jump for the head.

Comment: it is obvservable, take a look at this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/561905/significant-increase-in-booting-time-after-update-in-ubuntu-14-04)